# Android: ссылка на контакт Skype в TextView

Tags: java, android, skype, mobile-development, android-intent

Как сделать ссылку на контакт Skype в TextView?

TextView распознает ссылки типа URL, e-mail и т.п., но не распознает ссылки на Skype.

Пробовал: `skype:мой_id`, `tel:мой_id`, `call:мой_id` — не работает.

Информацию по данному вопросу в интернете не нашел.
Есть ли вообще в Android возможность запуска Skype по ссылке, на подобии как в Web??

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intent для запуска скайпа с нужной url создаётся [так](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn745884.aspx):

```
Uri skypeUri = Uri.parse(mySkypeUri);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, skypeUri);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.skype.raider", "com.skype.raider.Main"));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Поддерживаемые форматы URL'ок описаны [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn745882.aspx).

Далее надо сделать линки скайпа в тексте кликабельными и ловить клики, что бы перейти в скайп. Как сделать перехват кликов по ссылкам описано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16644228/2893248), а что бы сделать ссылками то что по формату TextView ссылкой не считает надо завернуть эти ссылки в тэг `<a href='skype:username'>skype:username</a>` и текст с этими ссылками пропустить через метод `Html.fromHtml`.

Comment: То, что нужно. Только одно но: Skype запускается только если он не запущен, а если уже запущен, то ссылка никакого действия не имеет. Но, тут попробую сам разобраться. Спасибо.

Comment: Если вызывать чат с самим собой тогда конечно ссылка никакого действия иметь не будет )) Все работает. Спасибо.

Comment: ахах, вот скайп зараза, початиться с умным человеком не даёт)

Answer (score 2):

Это можно сделать с помощью `Intent`. Однако необходимо учитывать, что

1. В разных версиях Skype различаются имена пакетов;
2. Skype может быть вообще не установлен на данном конкретном девайсе.

Поэтому необходимо выполнять соответствующие проверки.

Подробный [пример](http://habrahabr.ru/post/131041/) реализации можно посмотреть на Хабре.